# Kops cluster on AWS timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops, kubectl, kops

This is really annoying me and I can't seem to find any answers on the internet.

I created a cluster using `kops` on AWS yesterday and everything worked fine. But for some reason (and this is like the 5th time it happens), I come back 1 or 2 days after and simply cannot access the cluster. All the other times my solution was to delete everything manually and create the cluster again.

Here's my kubectl client version

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:41:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Here's what I tried:

1. `kubectl get nodes/pods/services/etc -v 7`

```
I1116 22:17:09.368841    1689 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
I1116 22:17:09.369482    1689 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://<apiUrl>/api?timeout=32s
I1116 22:17:09.369501    1689 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I1116 22:17:09.369519    1689 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I1116 22:17:09.369535    1689 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.22.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/c920368
I1116 22:18:31.932298    1696 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 30003 milliseconds
I1116 22:18:31.932372    1696 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://<apiUrl>/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp <apiIP>: i/o timeout
```

2. update kops cluster
   `kops update cluster`

Nothing happened, `no changes need to be applied`

Does anyone have any idea what's happening? What am I missing in here?

I'm still a K8S noob, so if you need more info please ask, I'm not quite sure what information can be relevant here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the problem is that I was using small, burstable instances both for master and nodes. Those didn't meet the hardware requirements for K8S.